# Is there any Doucusign Android code example?

Tags: android, docusignapi

Is there any [mobile-android-sdk](https://github.com/docusign/mobile-android-sdk) complete code example where describe how to implement the whole docusing flow to sign a document, the Embedded Signing Ceremony? I can not find how to show the template on and Android app screen :( .

Answer (score 0):

We are planning to publish sample application integrated with DocuSign Android SDK in [mobile-android-sdk](https://github.com/docusign/mobile-android-sdk) in near future.
In the meanwhile, you can refer to the README documentation in [mobile-android-sdk](https://github.com/docusign/mobile-android-sdk).
Please find the flow below for signing ceremony using templates in reference to README documentation. Each of the following sections demonstrates the code usage in README.

- Initialization for OAuth Login
- Login using OAuth
- Get Templates
- GetTemplate
- CacheTemplate
- UseTemplate

UseTemplate api uses the template that is provided and completes the signing ceremony. This api launches the UI for completing the signing ceremony.

Comment: ok, thank you Naveen. I will try using UseTemplate api. Where I can find an example how to use DSEnvelopeDefaults?

Comment: UseTemplate api is returning an error "No template found" but, if I use the same templateId with GetTemplate api the response it's success, I got the DSTemplateDefinition.

Comment: Hi Alexandra, DSEnvelopeDefaults class is used to prefill the values in the template. You can pass null value for DSEnvelopeDefaults in useTemplate api. For DSEnvelopeDefaults documentation, you can checkout 'gh-pages' branch in [gh-pages](https://github.com/docusign/mobile-android-sdk/tree/gh-pages) and launch index.html for java documentation on sdk. Then, navigate to DSEnvelopeDefaults class in java doc. This is a temporary measure and we are going to provide link to java doc from the GitHub directly soon.

Comment: For ‘No template found’ error, you need to cache the template before invoking 'UseTemplate' api. You can cache the template using 'cacheTemplate' api.